# Tensorflow: Feeding placeholder from variable

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm feeding to tensorflow c**omputation(train) graph** using input queue and
`tf.train.batch` function that prepares huge tensor with data.
I have another queue with test data I would like to feed to graph every 50th step.

## Question

Given the form of the input (tensors) do I have to define separate **test graph** for test data computation or I can somehow reuse train grap?

```
# Prepare data
batch = tf.train.batch([train_image, train_label], batch_size=200)
batchT = tf.train.batch([test_image, test_label], batch_size=200)

x = tf.reshape(batch[0], [-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3])
y_ = batch[1]
xT = tf.reshape(batchT[0], [-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3])
y_T = batchT[1]

# Graph definition
train_step = ... # train_step = g(x)

# Session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(1000):
  if i%50 == 0: 
  # here i would like reuse train graph but with tensor x replaced by x_t
  # train_accuracy = ?
  # print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))

train_step.run(session=sess)
```

I would use **placeholders** but I can't feed `tf.placeholder` with `tf.Tensors` and this is the thing I'm getting from queues.
How is it supposed to be done?

I'm really just starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at how this is done in the [MNIST example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_preloaded_var.py): You need to use a placeholder with an initializer of the none-tensor form of your data (like filenames, or CSV) and then inside the graph, use the slice_input_producer -> deocde_jpeg (or whatever...) -> tf.train.batch() to create batches and feed those to the computation graph.

So your graph looks like something like:

- Placeholder initialized with big filenames list/CSV/range
- `tf.slice_input_producer`
- `tf.image.decode_jpeg` or `tf.py_func` - loading of the actual data
- `tf.train.batch` - create mini batches for training
- feed to your model

Comment: What i was really asking  is what is good design incorporating data input node into tensor graph. But I only know it now after few weeks :)